# How to change toggle button state from another activity

Tags: android, togglebutton

Here is my question,my app flow is **screen1,screen2,screen3**.and their content views are like this:

```
screen1.java-->screen1.xml
 screen2.java-->screen3.xml
 screen3.java-->screen3.xml
```

here in **screen1** if user clicks on toggle button to is going to **screen2** then **screen3** in **screen3** payment success then only **screen1** toggle button should change,how to achieve this,didn't get any idea,plz help me,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass button state using Bundle between activities like following

Start activity 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, VALUE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get that value in activity 2 like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
boolean value = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(EXTRA_VALUE);
}
```

same like above you can pass is to Activity 3.

Or

You can make a static variable in you Activity 1 and then access that from Activity 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state of toggle button in Shared preferences.
Check this : [Shared Preferences Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static global array list and save the pressed states at their positions in that list. In the next activities use that array list to set the toggle status of your buttons

This is similarly like saving the checked states of a checkbox in a listview

Answer (score 0):

You can make that toggle button static and then you can change its state from any activity.

```
 static ToggleButton  toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggle_btn);
```

but you need to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass the toggle state via intents and onActivityResult().

[Here is a video tutorial on intents](http://androiddev101.com/episode-2-intent-away/)

[Here is some a tutorial on onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)